# O que há de errado nesse formulário de busca?

Tags: php, mysql

Criei esse formulário de busca, portanto ele está retornando tudo em branco!

Aqui o formulário:

```
<h3>O que você esta procurando? Digite aqui:</h3>
        <form class="form-inline" action="busca.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="palavra" placeholder="Digite aqui..." name="palavra">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cidade">Selecione a cidade:</label>
                <select name="cidade" class="form-control" id="cidade">
                    <option value="sao-gabriel-da-palha">São Gabriel da Palha</option>
                    <option value="sao-domingos-do-norte">São Domingos do Norte</option>
                    <option value="vila-valerio">Vila Valério</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Buscar">Buscar</button>
        </form>
```

E aqui está os códigos que usei para fazer a conexão e a busca em PHP:

```
<?php

  $hostdb = "localhost";
        $userdb = "root";
        $passdb = "root";
        $tabledb = "empresa";

        $conecta = mysqli_connect($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
        @mysqli_connect($tabledb, $conecta) or die("Erro ao se conectar com o banco de dados");

        $busca = $_POST['palavra'];
        $cidade = $_POST ['cidade'];

        $busca_query = mysqli_query($conecta,"SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' AND cidade = '$cidade'") or die(mysqli_error());

        if (empty($busca_query)){
            echo "Nenhum resultado para a sua busca.";
        }

        if ($busca_query){
            while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($busca_query)){
                echo "Nome: $dados[nome]</br>";
                echo "Endereço: $dados[endereco]</br>";
                echo "Cidade: $dados[cidade]</br>";
                echo "Telefone: $dados[telefone]</br>";
                echo "email: $dados[email]</br>";
                echo "<hr>";
}
        }else{
            echo "Nenhum resultado para a sua busca.";
        }


        ?>
```

Alguém poderia me explicar porque a consulta está retornando em branco?

Comment: Precisa passar a conexão como primeiro argumento em `mysqli_query()` e em `mysqli_error()`

Comment: Dê um exemplo disso ai pra mim, pois sou novato, ainda estou aprendendo!

Answer (score 5):

O erro principal ocorre porque `mysqli_query()` espera exatamente dois argumentos o primeiro é sempre conexão e o segundo a consulta.

Mude:

```
 $busca_query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' AND cidade = '$cidade'") or die(mysqli_error());
```

Para:

```
$busca_query = mysqli_query($conecta, "SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' AND cidade = '$cidade'") or die(mysqli_error($conecta));
```

Outros problemas são a função `mysqli_error()` também pede a conexão se ela não existir você não pode verificar o erro ao chamar `mysqli_connect()` nesse caso de estabelecer a conexão o correto é chamar `mysqli_connect_error()` ou `mysqli_connect_errno()`.

Pode eliminar a chamada de `mysqli_select_db()` passando como o nome do banco de dados como quarto argumento em `mysqli_connect()`

Mude:

```
$conecta = mysqli_query($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Para:

```
$conecta = mysqli_connect($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
```

Estruture melhor o if, caso o retorno da consulta seja falso ainda assim o bloco do while será executado que gerará um erro. Deixe ele da seguinte forma:

```
if ($busca_query){
    while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($busca_query)){
        echo "Nome: $dados['nome']</br>";
        echo "Endereço: $dados['endereco']</br>";
        echo "Cidade: $dados['cidade']</br>";
        echo "Telefone: $dados['telefone']</br>";
        echo "email: $dados['email']</br>";
        echo "<hr>";         
    }
}else{  
    echo "Nenhum resultado para a sua busca.";
}
```

Comment: Ainda continua trazendo o resultado em branco! Será que tem algum outro erro??

Comment: @WPfan testou a consulta direto no banco de dados?

Comment: Não, dessa forma não testei. Fiz todas as alterações que vc recomendou e continua retornando em branco, nem a mensagem de nenhum resultado encontrado aparece!

Comment: @WPfan primeiro vc deve chamar o `mysqli_connect()` só para depois chamar `mysqli_query()` veja no código q vc chama `mysqli_query()` como se fosse o `mysqli_connect()` => `mysqli_query($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb) `

Comment: Bem, já começou a melhorar, agora ao menos está aparecendo a mensagem Erro ao se conectar com o banco de dados! E agora, porque será que esta dando erro na conexão?

Comment: @WPfan pode ser N coisas usuário e senha inválidos etc, qual foi a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Ele imprimiu o erro dessa linha aqui:

@mysqli_connect($tabledb, $conecta) or die("Erro ao se conectar com o banco de dados");

Comment: @WPfan vc não deve usar `@` no seu código elas ocultam os erros. vc tem chamar os argumentos na ordem certa, primeiro o endereço do servidor, usuário do banco, senha e o nome do banco de de dados (opcional) igual a `$conecta = mysqli_connect($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb)`

Comment: fiz o teste e ainda dando Erro ao se conectar com o banco de dados

Comment: @rray  mysqli_connect() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in ... on line 9    linha 9    mysqli_connect($tabledb, $conecta) or die("Erro ao se conectar com o banco de dados");  Sem o @

Comment: Caramba, como pode uma coisa tão simples de fazer está dando tanta dor de cabeça

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo minha resposta foi em cima da primeira versão (engraçado q n vi as outras duas) n tem essa chamada com dois argumentos.

Comment: @WPfan o código correto fica dessa forma: https://pastebin.com/GWXSWAzE

Comment: no codigo existem 2 linhas $conecta = mysqli_connect.. E  @mysqli_connect($ta ....

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo nessa última edição tem essa linha mas ela está errada e também não é necessário já que a primeira faz da maneira correta. Não sei se a explicação com a correção ficaram confusas ou bagunçadas na resposta, montei esse link https://pastebin.com/GWXSWAzE com o código certo. A resposta diz basicamente modifique três pontos, (connect(), query() e o if).

Comment: @WPfan aparece algum erro? o nome do banco é empresa mesmo/?

Comment: Desculpem o nome do banco é guianortecapixaba, eu alterei e continua a mesma coisa

Comment: @WPfan não é possivel, testei o código do rray e está rodando bem veja aqui com o codigo dele http://kithomepage.com/sos/Product.php

Comment: agora posso dar +1, rodando redondo o que está no pastebin!

Answer (score 0):

Bem para eu conseguir fazer e dar certo, teve que ser dessa forma aqui, agradeço por todos pela ajuda:

```
<?php
        $servidor = "localhost";
        $usuario = "root";
        $senha = "root";
        $tabela = "guianortecapixaba";

        $conexao = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $tabela);

        if ($conexao->connect_error) {
            die("Erro: " . $conexao->connect_error);
        }

        $busca = $_POST['palavra'];
        $cidade = $_POST ['cidade'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' AND cidade = '$cidade'";
        $resultados = $conexao->query($sql);

        if ($resultados->num_rows > 0) {
            while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
                print("Nome: " . $linha['nome'] . "</br>");
                print ("Endereço:". $linha['endereco']."</br>");
               // print ("Cidade:". $linha['cidade']."</br>");
                print ("Telefone:". $linha['telefone']."</br>");
                echo "email:". $linha['email']."</br>";
                echo "<hr>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Nenhum resultado para a sua busca.";
        }

        $conexao->close();
```